# Is it possible to disable all pull request merges into a particular branch while a build is running for that branch?

Tags: github, continuous-integration

We are using GitHub and CircleCI. I know that pull request mergeability can be made to be dependent on the most recent commit, using status checks. Is there any way to make it depend on whether or not a build is running? How?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Does Circle CI supports comcurrent builds for the same reposistory? Could not just disable comcurrent builds?

Comment: @Laiv merely preventing concurrent builds is not sufficient; we want to prevent new commits to the branch while the build is running.

Comment: @DDrmmr we want to push a commit as part of the build process. Disabling merges while a build is running is the safest and simplest way to ensure that the  push does not fail.

Comment: @Laiv No, that's not why. See my response to DDrmmr.

Comment: if your CI tool allows you to use hooks before/after building process, you could make a branch protected so no one can push, and disable that protection again. I would not recommend locking pull requests though, you might want to review your process. Just providing you with an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo. Any particular reason you discourage locking pull requests?

Comment: I did some more googling based on @Gonzalo.-'s answer and found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573334/11342032

Comment: this really belongs in a product specific forum, not one on software architecture and design.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push a commit as part of the build process, my recommendation would be to do it in a separate branch. Maybe call it `release` or `builds` or something.  Then just limiting to one concurrent build would ensure no conflicts. Alternately, if what you are pushing is a version number, you could consider using [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) instead. If it's some other kind of artifact, you might consider using an artifact repository like [artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/). Those are more designed for the outputs of builds, whereas git repositories are designed to hold the inputs to builds.

The reason locking merges is discouraged is it incentivizes developers to circumvent the normal process. So you might find them doing things like merging pull requests into each other, or otherwise making their pull requests larger than they normally would, in order to be able to get a pull request off their plate.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response, I will take this into consideration. We are looking to commit renamed database migration files; the names are changed from timestamped versioning to sequential versioning. We use the [Goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose) migration tool and this is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: So, you are versioning the DB schema in the same reposistory than source code. Right? Ca not you make a dedicated repository for these Files?

Comment: @Laiv That's an interesting idea, I'll have to give it some thought.

Comment: This way, they can also have their own CI cycle and testing. Say you make a little runtime with Java+H2DB to load all the SQL sequentally, make some checks like selects or inserts and destroy the db at the end of the pipeline.